# Unity (5.5) Plugin using SQLite database error when export Windows application file (EXE)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sqlite

I'm developing Unity Plugin using Unity 5.5.6f1

The Plugin wrap SQLite calls and provide function to call in Unity like this

```
// Unity Plugin
public void doSomething()
{
    // Query DB.
}
```

Using in Unity game project.

```
// Unity
unityPluginInstance.doSomething();
```

I built the Plugin into DLL, put it in the Unity game project, it works well when I click "Play" on Unity Editor.

However, when I try to export Unity game project into EXE file, it throws a lot of errors.

```
ArgumentException: The Assembly System.Data.Entity is referenced by System.Data.SQLite.Linq ('Assets/Plugins/MyPlugin/System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll'). But the dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found.
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.AddReferencedAssembliesRecurse (System.String assemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 alreadyFoundAssemblies, System.String[] allAssemblyPaths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 cache, BuildTarget target) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:147)
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.FindAssembliesReferencedBy (System.String[] paths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, BuildTarget target) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:184)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

I have searched a lot on Google but can't find any working solutions.

Can anyone teach me how to fix this error? Thank you very much.

Comment: MyPlugin imports the `System.Data.SQLite.Linq` DLL which requires the `System.Data.Entity` DLL. The issue is that Untiy cannot find the `System.Data.Entity` DLL at build time, but can during run-time in the game window. My guess is that something in Unity requires this DLL, or it's registered in your GAC. I'm not overly familiar with the unity build process, but look to see if there is a 'libraries' or 'imports' folder you could place the DLL in, also be sure to run Unity as an administrator just in case your DLL resides in a system directory. Or simply google 'include dll in unity build'.

Comment: @JacobPersi: Thank you for your comment. Fortunately I found the solution and I wrote it in the answer. If you interested in this problem, you can take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after post my question to Stackoverflow, I found the solution.

Just in the Reference, select System.Data.Entity and edit its property "Copy Local" to True.

After building the Plugin, System.Data.Entity.dll will appear in the output folder. We will add this file to Unity game/app project along with MyPlugin.DLL and other files.

The problem is fixed.

[image]